# page refresh permanently when html5 true in angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dotnetnuke

i use angular v1.6.3 and angular-ui-router v0.4.2

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
var home = {
      name: 'home',
      url: '/',
      template: 'Hello {{name}}',
      controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) 
      $scope.name = "World";
      console.log("asdasd");
   }]
};
$stateProvider.state(home);
```

and i set the base tag

```
<base href="/CheckOut/">
```

when i open the page my browser start refreshing and never stop

http://www.ahp.ir/test

this is a real test on my web site build with dotnetnuke

when i check this code in simple html that work fine but on the dnn not worked.

Comment: can you add your routes or does it only have the .otherwise rule ?

Comment: when i define my route for example state:/user it work but the state:/ not work and refresh the page

Comment: if i dont use html5 its work and dont refreshing the page but i need to use html5

Comment: it seems like a routing problem to me but you`ll need to add some scripts so people can help

Comment: http://www.ahp.ir/test/ 
it seems be ok i add another route and change the position of page